# Windows 10 File Explorer does not recognize optical discs

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, optical-drive

I'm running Windows 10 and the File Explorer won't display the contents of discs in my optical drive. The weird thing about this is that I can still use the drive. When I put an audio CD in there and open up VLC Media Player and pick "Open Disc..." it plays the music just fine. So the drive hardware and the connection to the rest of the computer work fine.

But when I open up the Windows File Explorer and go to "DVD RW Drive (G:)" I just get an empty file list with a message that says "Drag files to this folder to add them to the disc." I used a professionally made audio CD, not a home writable or rewritable disc, and all parts are original/legal.

The same thing happened when I tried two other music CDs and one disc of non-audio files. The non-audio disc was the driver disc that came with my printer. It's supposed to autoplay a setup window, but now nothing happens and I get that same blank disc message. All four CDs work fine in other machines.

Also, this problem is not new. Something like this happened a long time ago (months at least) on the same computer but it went away on its own or maybe I found a workaround, I don't remember. I didn't notice again until now but probably just cause I don't use the CD/DVD drive a lot. I'm pretty sure this didn't happen before upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 though.

My attempts to search for this mostly led to posts about an entire drive being broken or not recognized, or about a drive reading okay but burning/ripping not working. My problem is in between. Windows shows the drive in the big list of drives on my computer, it just always thinks it's empty. How do I get File Explorer to recognize my discs?

Comment: The obvious questions: How many data discs have you tried, and have you verified that they are good by reading them in another machine?

Comment: Three audio and one file-data, and they do work fine in other machines.